# Aptana git reverting

Tags: git, aptana, aptana3

Is it possible to revert a commit or merge in Aptana?
I only have found the option to revert untagged changes.

But is it possible to revert certain commits or a merge with Aptana or do I have to use the command line?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be directly supported.
You do have a ["revert" action](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Git#Git-Revertingfiles)

> Reverting will discard any unstaged changed to a file

But that isn't the same than a `git revert`.

You also have the possibility to revert changes, but only one you are currently doing since your last changed (as mentioned in the [ticket 304](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/suggestions/304-revision-control)). Again not the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if it possible with egit or jgit plugin? If yes I would you these instead of the Aptana git.

Comment: @user1058712: yes, Egit supports a much more complete range of revert actions: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Reverting_Changes